# Edit in list view (role/permissions) in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm looking for a solutions where I can do the following in my **Sonata** backend:

[image]

In my database I have the following tables:

- **roles**

  - id
  - name
  - role
  - is_super_admin
  - weight
- **permissions**

  - name
  - permissions
  - description
- **role_permission** (many to many)

  - role_id
  - permission_id

So I would like to save relations in my table **role_permission**. But I'm a bit stuck on how to do this in Sonata admin. Can I do this in the list view? And if yes, can you help me on my way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if OP wants to implement custom roles or use existing features. However I would recommend using a single role system. Sonata already has handlers for security so in my opinion it would be best to use those instead of creating your own.

On the sonata site, there is [a section in the admin bundle about security](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/security.html). Which explains how to setup certain types of role management. I would either go for the Role or ACL handler depending on what you need.

When enabling the role handler you can create groups of roles. These groups would serve as your "Role 1". For example I could create a group called "Beta Testers" and give them the ROLES (permissions) `ROLE_CHECK_BETA_CONTENT` and `ROLE_BETA_FEEDBACK_FORM`. Now if you want normal users to not have these rights you could create a normal user group and assign every other role (permission).